# Multiple errors of : 18456 on the SQL Server (And in the Event Viewer)

Tags: sql-server-2016

> **Alert Details**
>
> **Host** xx-x-xx-xx-0xx **Application** MSSQLSERVER **EventID** 18456 **Criticality** High
>
> **Time** 20:29:50, Sun, May 28 2017
>
> **Message** Login failed for user 'xyz'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: xx.xx.xxx.xxx].

I'm getting 1000+ alerts regarding the same error mentioned above.

Most importantly: I get these alerts whenever the maintenance plans (Backup) are executed.

Can anyone please explain **why** am I getting the error 18456 and then the maintenance plan runs successfully anway?

Answer (score 0):

This is very typical SQL problem of SQL user rights. please check if you are using AD account/ service account, it happens that rights use to get revoked while some specific SQL command is being executed.Check with your IT team regarding your SQL account.